# PHP error after adding new field

Tags: entry, error-message, php

I've added many fields in the past with success but today, on my local MAMP server, after adding a new field to a Matrix and saving, I'm getting a PHP error when I try to view the entry's admin page, the page preview, or try to add a new entry.

Thankfully removing that field and saving gets me back to where I was. The CMS is up to date. Here is the error when trying to view the entry's admin, I can post more if it helps (the stack trace has 70+ errors in it):

[image: PHP error]
When creating a new entry, the error is also on BaseOptionsFieldType.php but line 362:

`if ($option['value'] == $value)`

Would anyone have any ideas for getting around this? The field I want to add is a Lightswitch but I get the same error when trying a Plain Text field.

Comment: A little work around would be to check if the key in this array is set/exists to not get the error. Do you have the latest craft version?

Comment: Is it a particularly large Matrix field?  How many blocks/fields are in it?

Comment: Thanks both. Robin I got the error on an older version from a few months ago, but I updated and got more-or-less the same error. Brad, the Matrix field has 12 block types set up, with each of those averaging three fields. Some of those fields use Super Tables and a couple of those have Dropdowns with around 15 options (think I'll rework things there when I get a chance!). You've led me to the solution - I will post it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing a few of the options from one of the Dropdowns within the Matrix and lo-and-behold, the errors are gone. Thanks so much! I guess I hit some kind of limit?